# C User-defined function issue

Tags: c, function, defined

So my program asks for name and numbers, then tallies up the number of even entries and odd entries, then giving a total of all the even entries and a total for all the odd.

It all works except the calculations, it tells me I have all odd entries and only values them as 1 when adding them up.

I feel like it has something to do with my variables and referencing in my calc function

```
#include <stdio.h>
int number = 1;
int evencount, oddcount;
int eventotal, oddtotal;



int main () {


char name[256];



printf("Enter your name \n");
scanf("%s", name);

printf("Enter numbers within 1-100 \n");
printf("Enter 0 to quit\n");
calc(number);


printf("%s,the numbers you have entered are broken down as follows: \n", name);

printf("%d odd entries \n", oddcount);

printf("%d even entries\n", evencount);

printf("You entered even numbers with a total value of %d \n", eventotal );
printf("You entered odd numbers with a total value of %d \n", oddtotal);

return 0;

}

int calc (int input) {

while (number != 0) {
    scanf("%d", &number);
    if (input%2 == 1) {
        oddcount++;
        oddtotal += input;
    }
    else {
        evencount++;
        eventotal += input;

    }
};

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
scanf("%d", &number);
if (input%2 == 1) {
{
    oddcount++;
    oddtotal += input;
}
```

I think you probably want `number % 2` rather than `input % 2`,
`oddtotal += number` rather than `oddtotal += input`, etc.

Comment: Ahh, I knew I had some problem with the naming conventions and which variables to use, thank ya!

Answer (score 1):

In your `calc` function, you're mixing up `input`, which is a parameter, and `number`, which is a global.

Using a global here for your input variable is bad form, and in fact you don't need to pass anything into this function.

Also, better to use `do..while` instead of `while` since the loop must run at least once:

You're also using the function before it's declared, so you should have a function prototype.  And since `calc` doesn't need to return anything, set its return type to `void`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int evencount, oddcount;
int eventotal, oddtotal;

void calc();

int main()
{
    ...
    calc();
    ...
}

void calc()
{
    int number;

    do {
        scanf("%d", &number);
        if (number%2 == 1) {
            oddcount++;
            oddtotal += number;
        } else {
            evencount++;
            eventotal += number;
        }
    } while (number != 0);
}
```